# werden oder werden sein

Tags: sentence-structure, future

Ich habe in der Nachricht auf der Internet-Seite den folgenden Satz gesehen

> Jüdische Einrichtungen werden in Sachsen-Anhalt künftig besser
>   geschützt.

Und somit die Frage: soll man `werden geschützt` oder `werden geschützt sein` sagen?

`Will the be protected better` in the future or they're `becoming` better protected now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beide Varianten sind möglich.

> Jüdische Einrichtungen **werden** in Sachsen-Anhalt künftig besser **geschützt**.

Das ist *werden+Partizip II* → **Präsens Vorgangspassiv**.

> Jüdische Einrichtungen **werden** in Sachsen-Anhalt künftig besser *geschützt* ***sein***.

Das ist *werden+Infinitiv* → **Futur I**, sowie *sein+Partizip II* → **Zustandspassiv**, also **Futur I Zustandspassiv**.

Da das Präsens im Deutschen auch die Zukunft ausdrücken kann, insbesondere wenn es mit Zeitwörtern wie *künftig* steht, unterscheiden sich die beiden Sätze nur in der Form des Passivs. Das Zustandspassiv hat einen vollendeten Aspekt, denn man betrachtet ja einen Zustand. Das Vorgangspassiv unterstreicht, dass es sich um kontinuierliche Anstrengungen handelt, was in diesem Fall besser passt.

Eine dritte Möglichkeit ist

> Jüdische Einrichtungen **werden** in Sachsen-Anhalt (künftig) besser *geschützt* ***werden***.

Das ist *werden+Infinitiv* → **Futur I**, sowie *werden+Partizip II* → **Vorgangspassiv**, also **Futur I Vorgangspassiv**.

Wegen des Wortes *künftig* im ersten Satz ist dieser Satz inhaltlich gleichwertig zum ersten Satz.

Answer (score 2):

Das sind sehr unterschiedliche Ausdrücke.  "Jüdische Einrichtungen werden in Sachsen-Anhalt künftig besser geschützt." bedeutet, daß besagte Einrichtungen in Zukunft besser geschützt *werden* werden, während "Jüdische Einrichtungen werden in Sachsen-Anhalt künftig besser geschützt sein" bedeutet, daß sie besser geschützt *sein* werden.

Ersteres betont die Verbesserung der unternommenen Anstrengungen, letzteres die Verbesserung des erzielten Ergebnisses.